# Sublime Text 3 (OSX) -- "Find in Files" not showing actual results

Tags: macos

I am currently running Sublime Text 3 on OSX.  I am running into an issue where when searching using Find In Files (Command+Shift+F), I am presented with something like the following:

```
Searching 1 file for "RQNT"

~/Downloads/MGCP-FXO Log:
    <binary>

4 matches in 1 file
```

The problem is that it doesn't actually show the matches, it just shows a count.  I have tried many versions of regex, use buffer/no buffer, show context/no context and it has no appreciable effect on the results.

I am thinking it may be some setting somewhere but I can't figure it out.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried a test search in another file for some simple search like "int" or "if" to confirm search functionality? Your example for "RQNT" shows its in a binary file only so you can't show the matches in that file.

Comment: It's always something so simple... So I made a new file and copied some of the text from the old file and was able to search fine. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: So I guess now my question becomes, is anyone aware of a terminal application for OSX that saves to txt and not binary?  I typically have to dig through log files and having to copy the data over to a file type that is searchable would be cumbersome.  It would be helpful if it would save directly to a supported file type.

Comment: You should probably ask a new question, it's not considered good form to ask big questions like that in comments

Comment: My apologies, I will open a new question.  Thanks for the guidance.